# Help on running a previous version of Java on Mac OS 10.5.8 and 10.6.6

Tags: java, mac

Can you help?

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2723030&tstart=0

I've zero knowledge on programming but overall saavy with computers.

Best!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably downgrade Java the following way:

1. Find and download the previous Java update (maybe it's still cached somewhere in your system folders)
2. Download [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/)
3. [Install](http://chxor.chxo.com/post/183013153/installing-java-1-5-on-snow-leopard) Java from the older Update (instructions are for 10.6 but I hope it's the same in 10.5).

Another option is to try selecting different Java framework for the application, e.g. 1.6 instead of 1.5. It can be done by right clicking on the application bundle and selecting Show Package Contents. A window appears. In the window locate and open with a text editor Contents/Info.plist. Here find `JVMVersion` key and modify the corresponding string.